# Caching dynamic pages in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, caching, dynamic

This is our setup:

> Windows 2003 Server Standard, SQL 2005 and ASP.NET 4.0.

We have a news site where URLs are structured like `www.domain.com/This-is-my-headline-123.aspx` - where 123 is the ID pointing at a record in the SQL database.

Is it possible to do caching based on this URL and if so, how would this be accomplished? I have looked at VaryByParam option of the ASP.NET caching, e.g.

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="*"%>
```

But I am unsure what the best practice would be. I have read this:

[Is DiskCacheProvider in ASP.Net 4.0 really exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312352/is-diskcacheprovider-in-asp-net-4-0-really-exist) with disk caching and I think this is the way to go - but do you guys/gals have some input for optimal techniques to improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use VaryByParam to vary the output cache based on query string or POST parameters.

In the case you describe, what you want is VaryByCustom. To make that work, override the GetVaryByCustomString() method in Global.asax. ASP.NET will store a different version of the page for each unique string you return from that method.

Comment: thanks, but I am not sure I understand it fully. I add something like this to Global.asax:  
  
  
`public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)  
{  
    if(arg == "headline")  
    {  
        return "what?";  
    }  
    return String.Empty;  
}`  

Then what am I supposed to write instead of the "what?" in the return statement?

Comment: Use the context argument to access Request and the incoming URL. Parse the URL to obtain the ID string, and return that (or maybe just the entire URL if it's always the same and unique). For good form, don't forget to call base.GetVaryByCustomString() if your code doesn't know about the incoming arg.

Comment: thank you - it helps :) the msdn article confused a little bit.